# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket' in GAE using Braintree

Tags: python, google-app-engine, braintree

I am testing an app in the Google App Engine that embeds the Braintree platform. I am using their code for this test to process a fictitious transaction. In my html I have a form that when submitted it routes its information to "/create_transaction" below. The server code is:

```
@app.route("/create_transaction", methods=["POST"])
def create_transaction():
    result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
        "amount": "1000.00",
        "credit_card": {
            "number": request.form["number"],
            "cvv": request.form["cvv"],
            "expiration_month": request.form["month"],
            "expiration_year": request.form["year"]
        },
        "options": {
            "submit_for_settlement": True
        }
    })
    if result.is_success:
        return "<h1>Success! Transaction ID: {0}</h1>".format(result.transaction.id)
    else:
        return "<h1>Error: {0}</h1>".format(result.message)
```

Instead of returning the result, the browser renders an Internal Server Error 500. The Traceback is the following:

```
ERROR    2014-09-26 03:08:13,852 app.py:1423] Exception on /create_transaction [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/app.py", line 40, in create_transaction
    "submit_for_settlement": True
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/braintree/transaction.py", line 302, in sale
    return Transaction.create(params)
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/braintree/transaction.py", line 397, in create
    return Configuration.gateway().transaction.create(params)
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/braintree/transaction_gateway.py", line 33, in create
    return self._post("/transactions", {"transaction": params})
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/braintree/transaction_gateway.py", line 137, in _post
    response = self.config.http().post(url, params)
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/braintree/util/http.py", line 49, in post
    return self.__http_do("POST", path, params)
  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/braintree/util/http.py", line 71, in __http_do
    raise e
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

Why is GAE throwing this exception?

Comment: That's located in the braintree code, so I'd say it's related to it, not to GAE. Has it been tested to work with GAE? Is it trying to do something not allowed in the sandboxed model of GAE?

Comment: I tested the same script locally in my computer and it worked. I do not think it is trying to do something not allowed because it simply tries to POST the transaction by sending the credit card information, which in my case it is a fake one. So it actually is just numbers being sent through the socket.

Comment: Your code uses an @app decorator. The issue comes from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

This appears to be a [problem with certain versions of urllib3 / requests (a Braintree dependency) on GAE](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/446#issuecomment-54079528).

Try adding this to your `app.yaml` file:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

And make sure you have billing enabled for the application.

If that doesn't solve it, you can see the github issue linked above for more info.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to review this. I added the library and enabled billing as described in the issue in the link above. However, I have the following error:

  File "/home/manuel/Google/braintree_app/braintree/util/http.py", line 71, in __http_do
    raise e
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))

This looks like I am not able to access the library because of a disabled billing in GAE, but I can confirm that billing is enabled. I am stuck.

Comment: @ManuelGodoy I think we responded to your support ticket, but for anyone else reading -- as mentioned in the issue I linked in the answer, you may need to have billing enabled to use the socket library from Python on GAE.

Comment: As I said in my comment billing is enabled and problem persists.

Comment: @ManuelGodoy Can you check what `requests.__version__` is inside your app? Let us know if you're able to find a resolution, but if not I can spend some time trying it myself on Friday and I want to make sure to replicate your setup as closely as possible.

Comment: __version__ = '2.4.1'

Comment: @ManuelGodoy did you try with 2.3? A couple of people in the linked issue mentioned that solved the problem for them.

Comment: @ManuelGodoy Check out my sample integration at https://github.com/agfor/braintree-python-appengine and the app running against the Braintree sandbox at http://braintree-python.appspot.com/ -- I didn't have any problems with the deployed app with billing enabled and the `ssl` section in my `app.yaml`. See the comments in main.py for getting it working while developing locally. I didn't have any problems with requests 2.4.1.

Comment: I can add that I am testing with appengine and the client token generation does work in production appengine with billing enabled.  It does not seem to work in the appengine dev server environment.  But that is okay.

Comment: @RalphYozzo Take a look at https://github.com/agfor/braintree-python-appengine/blob/master/main.py#L28-L36 -- that should make dev mode work.